# How do you CASE out the unknowns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, pivot

I ran into a problem when selecting a count into multiple columns with a CASE statement. How the CASE statement works for me is like a IF statement in C/C++. IF the value equals X, then do Y ELSE do Z.

To help explain this problem, let me provide a query that counts names within a column called 'Names' and groups them by a 'Date' column.

```
SELECT [Date]
       COUNT( CASE WHEN [Name] = 'John' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'John',
       COUNT( CASE WHEN [Name] = 'Joe' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Joe',
       COUNT( CASE WHEN [Name] = 'Moe' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Moe',
       COUNT( CASE WHEN [Name] = 'Nick' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Nick',
       COUNT( CASE WHEN [Name] = 'Zack' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Zack'
FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[LogInData]
WHERE [Date] >= '2013-07-01'
GROUP BY [Date]
```

This assumes I know the names I want to count. What if I wanted to count the names that are new and not defined in my query IN a single row? How can I make this dynamically search for all DISTINCT names in a table and count them separately as above automatically without having to adding new names to the code?

Thanks for any help you can provide. I'm still trying to learn different ways to utilize SQL for complex query writing. I'm not looking for an exact answer, but any help to point me in the right direction would be great. I'm all for learning and expanding my knowledge as opposed to things given to me.

Comment: You'll need to use dynamic sql to do this.  I'd recommend you `select [date], [name], count(1)....` then handle the pivot in your presentation layer.

Comment: You are on 2008 or better I assume

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would do it the other way:

```
SELECT [Date], [Name], COUNT(*)
  FROM ...
  GROUP BY [Date], [Name];
```

Then perhaps you could pivot, but you don't necessarily have to do that in the query. Doing so when not knowing the names you have (and therefore the number of columns) will require dynamic SQL to construct a proper pivot - but again, you can transpose this information at the presentation layer and let SQL Server return this data the way it's optimized to do.

```
DECLARE @date date = '20130701';

DECLARE @sql  nvarchar(max) = N'', 
        @cols nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(Name)
               FROM dbo.LoginData
               WHERE [Date] >= @date
               GROUP BY Name
               FOR XML PATH(''),
               TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');

SET @sql = N'SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.LoginData AS d
  WHERE [Date] >= @date
  ) AS d
  PIVOT (COUNT([Name]) FOR [Name] IN (' + @cols + ')) AS p;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@date date', @date;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cd4d6cbf1cedb8909c95717a9d725a1c)

Comment: View logic in the database is evil.

Comment: Man, you guys are quick today. I added a bit at the bottom that an exact answer is not ideally needed. Any helpful direction where I can learn more about solving this problem on my own is good enough too. But, thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: @Fastidious well you haven't commented on whether or not having these returned on the same row by SQL Server is really a requirement. If this is to simplify the client-side coding I'd suggest that you also look at ways to make the client-side code manipulate the data presented by SQL Server in the traditional way as I've shown with the group by.

Comment: Thanks! I'll specify. It needs to be returned in the same row so I can merge the counts horizontally as one record.

Comment: Oh man, that looks good! Could I trouble you for some comments explaining a bit how this code is working for piece of mind? You don't have too, but figured I would ask because I'm trying to break down what you did here.

Comment: The STUFF line just looks at every distinct name in the set, and builds a comma-separated list. e.g. `[Bob],[Frank]`. The rest is the standard syntax for [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx), which requires the hard-coded list of *known* column names at compile time, which is why the need for dynamic SQL.

Comment: So, it would be better to always query a known list of names rather than try to develop a query around a set of unknown names ideally? That is still a possibility, just trying to cover all ends of the unknowns in case of fire. :)

Comment: No, that's not what I said. :-) It's obviously not always possible or practical to know all the names in advance... you write the query and 5 minutes later a new user comes along, *poof*. What I did say is that the first form, where the results are vertical, allows you to not care what names are going to be there. And it should be pretty trivial to turn them horizontal in whatever application is *consuming* the results. This is why I asked multiple times if it's really a requirement - many folks just don't know that other applications can turn results horizontal when necessary.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I understand. I'm sitting here processing that question you posed on when to turn them horizontally. Which in my case, may not be needed in this particular example. The end result I'm trying to get to is a horizontal set of data where the names are rolled up with additional stats from other tables or views. This particular example is just counting the names for one table that will be used for a bigger query down the road. Turning them horizontal likely should be used later in that big query, but not here me thinks now.

Comment: SQL Server is most likely going to be better optimized to run the first query than the second.

Comment: Is that because vertical is better than horizontal?

Comment: Well, to some extent, yes - a table and its indexes are structured to optimize the first query - with an index on date/name or name/date, it can group and aggregate in a single pass, since the data will be already be roughly in the order you've defined. If you turn the table on its side, it has to work a lot differently.

Comment: ...it *may* ultimately boil down to the same optimizations, but I doubt in this case the dynamic pivot version will be as efficient as the group by (again, depending on indexes).

Comment: Yepyep, makes sense. Thanks for your help Aaron. I'm no DBA elite or SQL master. I'm just trying to do some cool stuff with data while learning more about SQL and especially, MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need them all in a single row, then you can just do:

```
SELECT [Date],
       [Name],
       COUNT(*)
FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[LogInData]
WHERE [Date] >= '2013-07-01'
GROUP BY [Date],[Name]
```

Comment: Yeah, need them in a single row. I'll specify in my original question. But, thanks for sharing this example too. This does help me understand other ways to count the names.